# Can't connect to MSSQL using django-pyodbc-azure 2.1.0.0

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

As the title says. Im getting this error

> django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Heres my code

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'HOST',
    'PORT': '',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
    },

}
}
DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOLING = False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first if you have that driver installed:

```
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

[Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

[Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)